# count and percent from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

These are the tables in the database

```
RMA

RMAID (PK)
OrderID (FK)
Step
Status
Reason



Orders

OrderID (PK)
CustomerID (FK)
SKU
Description



Customers

CustomerID (PK)
FirstName
LastName
StreetAddress
City
State
ZipCode
```

I'm trying to get a percentage of returns on an item. I would like to count the number of total of each item ordered and the total of each item returned I figured the best was to do this would be using the SKU in the Orders table, but I'm not sure how to write it up exactly. I have this so far.

```
select Orders.SKU,
COUNT(Orders.SKU) AS Ordered,
(COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)) AS Percent
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN RMA
ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.SKU;
```

That puts out a percent, but I'm not sure what the percent is exactly.
I also have this command, but I keep getting a syntax error.

```
select Orders.SKU,
COUNT(Orders.SKU) AS Ordered,
(COUNT(Orders.SKU) WHERE Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID) AS Returned,
(COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)) AS Percent
FROM Orders
JOIN RMA
ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.SKU;
```

Sorry about the long post I'm just trying to include as many details as possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

here is the result of the first command. where i can get it to output the percentage of sku. in the command i do not know what the percent it is putting out.

```
mysql> select Orders.SKU,
    -> COUNT(Orders.SKU) AS Ordered,
    -> (COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)) AS Percent
    -> FROM Orders
    -> INNER JOIN RMA
    -> ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
    -> GROUP BY Orders.SKU;
+------------+---------+---------+
| SKU        | Ordered | Percent |
+------------+---------+---------+
| ADV-24-10C |    4122 | 10.8479 |
| ADV-48-10F |    4124 | 10.8532 |
| BAS-08-1 C |    4248 | 11.1795 |
| BAS-24-1 C |      33 |  0.0868 |
| BAS-48-1 C |    8282 | 21.7959 |
| ENT-24-10F |    4231 | 11.1348 |
| ENT-24-40F |    2121 |  5.5819 |
| ENT-48-10F |    4287 | 11.2822 |
| ENT-48-40F |    6118 | 16.1008 |
+------------+---------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.55 sec)
```

here is the command i started to try and count the amount of times a sku appeard with its orderid in the rma table but i get this error.

```
mysql> select Orders.SKU,
    -> COUNT(Orders.SKU) AS Ordered,
    -> (COUNT(Orders.SKU) WHERE Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID) AS Returned,
    -> (COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)) AS Percent
    -> FROM Orders
    -> JOIN RMA
    -> ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
    -> GROUP BY Orders.SKU;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID) AS Returned,
(COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELE' at line 3
```

after running the suggested command it outputs the following.

```
mysql> select Orders.SKU,
    -> COUNT(Orders.SKU) AS Ordered,
    -> COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID THEN Orders.SKU ELSE NULL END) as Returned,
    -> (COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)) AS Percent
    -> FROM Orders
    -> JOIN RMA
    -> ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
    -> GROUP BY Orders.SKU;
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
| SKU        | Ordered | Returned | Percent |
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
| ADV-24-10C |    4122 |     4122 | 10.8479 |
| ADV-48-10F |    4124 |     4124 | 10.8532 |
| BAS-08-1 C |    4248 |     4248 | 11.1795 |
| BAS-24-1 C |      33 |       33 |  0.0868 |
| BAS-48-1 C |    8282 |     8282 | 21.7959 |
| ENT-24-10F |    4231 |     4231 | 11.1348 |
| ENT-24-40F |    2121 |     2121 |  5.5819 |
| ENT-48-10F |    4287 |     4287 | 11.2822 |
| ENT-48-40F |    6118 |     6118 | 16.1008 |
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
9 rows in set, 37566 warnings (0.05 sec)
```

which i know is progress and its looking closer to what i want out of it.

these are the warnings

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-08-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-08-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ADV-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ADV-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-08-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-08-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ADV-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ADV-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ADV-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ADV-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ADV-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-08-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-08-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-08-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-24-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-48-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'BAS-08-1 C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-40F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ADV-24-10C' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'ENT-48-10F' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
64 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: but I'm not sure how " to get a percentage of returns on an item " ?

Comment: Show an [mre], include (some) sample data. (and desired output)

Comment: i added an image of the first code and the result when it is ran in the terminal.

Comment: I do not like IMAGES, especially if they only contain TEXT. You could also have copy/pasted the TEXT.... (There is no advantage in posting this as an image!)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the number from 0 to 9 (including 9), see this example on how to get the percentage of number smaller than 3:

```
select 
   min(i),
   max(i),
   round(sum(case when i<=3 then 1 else 0 end)/count(i)*100,2) Percentage,
   group_concat(i) 
from numm;
```

returning:

```
+--------+--------+------------+---------------------+
| min(i) | max(i) | Percentage | group_concat(i)     |
+--------+--------+------------+---------------------+
|      0 |      9 |      40.00 | 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 |
+--------+--------+------------+---------------------+
```

Because 0,1,2,3 are `<=3`, and 4,5,6,7,8,9 are not `<=3`, `40` seems to be the correct percentage.

EDIT: Based on the final edit of your question, which now includes a proper error message:

Because you cannot have a `WHERE` in your query, you are getting a 'syntax error'

Inside your query you can conditionally count items using a [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) statement.

Try this :

```
select Orders.SKU,
COUNT(Orders.SKU) AS Ordered,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID THEN Orders.SKU ELSE NULL END) as Returned,
(COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)) AS Percent
FROM Orders
JOIN RMA
ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.SKU;
```

Comment: there edit to add the text output of the command. i dont think i fully understand your example.

Comment: Which part of the example do you not understand?

Comment: All of it, that's not what I' trying to do at all.

Comment: This example shows the most simple way of data for which one can count a percentage. If you do not understand this example then ..... ( I am lost.... )

Comment: part of what i need to do is to pull two counts of each SKU one where they appear in Orders table. and the second when the OrderID appears in RMA table.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67150264/edit) your question, and provide a [mre]. Show some sample input, and desired output. You are showing some SQL statement which produces a percentage, but you are not explaining if that is correct, or what is wrong with it.....

Comment: Okay I edited it to include what I got as a result of my commands. I'm trying to explain what I'm trying to do the best I can but i literally only have a few weeks into SQL, so my phrasing might be incorrect or what I'm trying to do might not be what I need.

Comment: Added a note about the syntax error, an how to resolve that.

Comment: thank you for that i tried that and posted the results. any idea what the warnings mean and how to fix them?

Comment: It must be something simple, but I have no clue, at least not now.....